# xpages and java frameworks

Tags: java, spring, struts2, struts, xpages

there seems to be a rising hype in XPages for web development.

so far all i see XPages is good for is quick development of Forms. It seems like a modern day version of VB

what are the advantages of using xpages as oppose to other java frameworks?

Answer (score 9):

XPages is IBM's web and mobile application development platform for collaborative and social applications. As other platforms it's based on standards like Java, JavaScript, JSF and OSGi.

The unique thing is that the infrastructure comes with everything you need to build and run applications. There is a built in document oriented database (though you can use relational databases), web server, directory, security, search functionality, etc. While the frontend part is rather new the backend components have been proven in production for almost two decades.

Another unique thing are the rapid development and deployment mechanisms. XPages are built with an Eclipse based tool supporting drag and drop functionality for simpler applications but also full Java capabilities for advanced programming. Since the document oriented databases can store both the design and the data complete applications can be easily deployed. Furthermore these databases can be easily replicated to other databases wherever they are located.

The community site http://xpages.info aggregates news, comes with demos, videos, open source applications, list resources and describes the technologies: http://xpag.es/?stackoverflow

Comment: Niklas, why not just use an existing frameworks such as struts, struts2, spring, stripes etc. ? I do not see the advantage of using XPages as oppose to J2EE frameworks. Is there an advantage?

Comment: @javabeans - the reason: existing investment in ibm/lotus domino apps. It's easier to migrate these to XPages than to do rewrite to a pure J2EE or ASP.NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

The main language of XPages is JavaScript. So you have JavaScript on the client and the server. This allows to loadbalance your development team better since they can work on both ends. Also Domino provides a robust NoSQL database (no more JDBC connection errors) that has an unparalleled declarative security model. Just by saving a respective field (type reader/author) you can define read/update access to every single record/document. This is WAY harder to do in any other platform (including Domino's mental offspring CouchDB). Domino is schema free, so the database never gets into the way of your rapid development cycle

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage of using XPages is the fact that it natively sits on top of a fully distributable and locally replicable data store that can be consumed by the Notes client.

The security model of the Notes NSF file is unmatched and so provides additional benefits beyond the standards-based extensible dev environment.